# avg-rt of [label] is not working in Taurus passfail

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

I am trying to run jmeter tests with Taurus. I have one JMX file with multiple Thread Groups. In other of the group, there is a request "InsertFolder" that takes more than 20secs however most of the other requests take around 5 secs. I have specified "avg-rt of InsertFolder > 10000ms, stop as failed" but not sure how to do it correctly.
This is the .yml file that I have:

```
reporting:
- module: passfail
  criteria:
  - avg-rt of InsertFolder > 10000ms, stop as failed 

execution:
- executor: jmeter
  concurrency: 1
  hold-for: 300s
  iterations: 10
  scenario: 
    script: standard.jmx
scenarios:
  standard:
    script: standard.jmx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to remove spaces in your [criterion](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) to wit change

```
avg-rt of InsertFolder > 10000ms, stop as failed
```

to

```
avg-rt of InsertFolder>1000ms, stop as failed
```

full [Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) just in case

```
reporting:
  - module: passfail
    criteria:
      - avg-rt of InsertFolder>10000ms, stop as failed

execution:
- executor: jmeter
  concurrency: 1
  hold-for: 300s
  iterations: 10
  scenario: 
    script: standard.jmx
scenarios:
  standard:
    script: standard.jmx
```

You may also find [The Complete Taurus Course](https://www.blazemeter.com/university/complete-taurus-course) useful